# gfortran adding spaces in continued line in write statement

Tags: fortran, format, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have a small fortran script writing data to a vtk file. On several occasions a write statement will do exactly what I intend it to do when compiling the script with ifort. With gfortran however it introduces unwanted spaces where the string is interrupted by a continued line (&) in the script. As a result, the written string becomes longer than intended and parts of it are not written since they are beyond the length of the format. One example is:

```
      write(21,'(A112)')'<VTKFile type="vtkMultiBlockDataSet" 
     &version="1.0" byte_order="LittleEndian"  
     &compressor="vtkZLibDataCompressor">"'
```

with ifort it gives

```
<VTKFile type="vtkMultiBlockDataSet" version="1.0" byte_order="LittleEndian" compressor="vtkZLibDataCompressor">
```

which is what i want. Gfortran produces:

```
<VTKFile type="vtkMultiBlockDataSet"           version="1.0" byte_order= "LittleEndian"
```

The problem are thus the extra spaces after "vtkMultiBlockDataSet" and "LittleEndian" which lead to a statement longer than the 112 characters given in the format. Are there any extra flags needed when compiling this with gfortran or what is the issue. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Is this using fixed-form source?  If so, please pay attention to how you format the code fragment.

Comment: Yes it is. But the & are all in the right position (6) which I unfortunately didn't paste properly here.

Comment: For fixed-form source, I address how to do continuation correctly in my answer to the linked question.  The problem you have here is that, because you don't mark the end of the string in the lines being continued, all of the blanks up to column 72 are included in the string.  If ifort is neglecting them, well...  You can add `'//` to the end of the line, adding `'` to the start of the next.